# Specific methodology to call a GRASS function like v.transform with Python

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis, function

I cannot understand if and how I can call with its parameters a GRASS function like v.transform through a Python script from e.g. PyCharm etc.
Is there something comprehensible to understand? An example would be very enlightening

Comment: Do you want to call the GRASS algorithm using the API of some software for example pygis?

Comment: Sounds fine if it works and I could see an example maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer lies into PyQGIS API, [documentation for QGIS 3](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf) which is a very helpful integrated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using PyGIS you can call the algorithm v.transform as follows::

```
plot_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('plot')[0]
output_path = '/tmp/transform.gpkg'
processing.run("grass7:v.transform",
                       {'input': plot_layer,
                       'xshift': 0,
                       'yshift': 0,
                       'zshift': 0,
                       'xscale': 1,
                       'yscale': 1,
                       'zscale': 1,
                       'zrotation': 0,
                       'columns': '',
                       'output': output_path,
                       'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None,
                       'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER': -1,
                       'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER': 0.0001,
                       'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 0,
                       'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO': '',
                       'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO': ''})

transform_layer = QgsVectorLayer(output_path, "transform_layer", "ogr")
```

Comment: Oh, I now understood what PyGIS is. Thanks a lot, however I would prefer something different and more universal maybe? Is an API the only solution available?